# Real Browser based load testing or Browser level user testing

Tags: browser, jmeter, performance-testing, simulation, loadrunner

I am currently working on multiple Load testing tool such as Jmeter, LoadRunner and Gatling.
All above tool works upon protocol level user load testing except TrueClient protocol offered by LoadRunner. Now something like real browser testing is in place which is definitely high on resources consumption tools such as LoadNinja and Flood.IO works on this novel concept.

I have few queries in this regards

1. What will be the scenario where real browser based load testing fits perfectly?
2. What real browser testing offers which is not possible in protocol based load testing?

I know, we can use Jmeter to Mimic browser behavior for load testing but is there anything different that real browser testing has to offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ....this novel concept.....

You're showing your age a bit here.  Full client testing was state of the art in 1996 before companies shifted en masse to protocol based testing because it's more efficient in terms of resources.  (Mercury, HP, Microfocus) LoadRunner, and (Segue, Borland, Microfocus) Silk, and (Rational, IBM) Robot, have retained the ability to use full GUI virtual users (run full clients using functional automation tools) since this time.  TruClient is a recent addition which runs a full client, but simply does not write the output to the screen, so you get 99% of the benefits and the measurements

What is the benefit.   Well, historically two tier client server clients were thick.  Lots of application processing going on.   So having a GUI Virtual user in a small quantity combined with protocol virtual users allowed you to measure the cost/weight of the client.   The flows to the server might take two seconds, but with the transform and present in the client it might take an addtional 10 seconds.  You now know where the bottleneck is/was in the user experience.

**Well, welcome to the days of future past.**  The web, once super thin as a presentation later, has become just as thick as the classical two tier client server applications.  I might argue thicker as the modern browser interpreting JavaScript is more of a resource hog than the two tier compiled apps of years past.   It is simply universally available and based upon a common client-server protocol - HTTP.

Now that the web is thick, there is value in understanding the delta between arrival and presentation.  You can also observe much of this data inside of the performance tab of Chrome.  We also have great w3c in browser metrics which can provide insight into the cost/weight of the local code execution.

Shifting the logic to the client also has resulted in a challenge on trying to reproduce the logic and flow of the JavaScript frameworks for producing the protocol level dataflows back and forth.  Here's where the old client-server interfaces has a distinct advantage, the protocols were highly structured in terms of data representation.  So, even with a complex thick client it became easy to represent and modify the dataflows at the protocol level (think database as an example, rows, columns....).  HTML/HTTP is very much unstructured.   Your developer can send and receive virtually anything as long as the carrier is HTTP and you can transform it to be used in JavaScript.

To make it easier and more time efficient for script creation with complex JavaScript frameworks the GUI virtual user has come back into vogue.   Instead of running a full functional testing tool driving a browser, where we can have 1 browser and 1 copy of the test tool per OS instance, we now have something that scale a bit more efficiently, Truclient, where multiple can be run per OS instance.  There is no getting around the high resource cost of the underlying browser instance however.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer your questions below:

***What will be the scenario where real browser based load testing fits perfectly?
What real browser testing offers which is not possible in protocol based load testing?***

Some companies do real browser based load testing. However, as you rightly concluded that it is extremely costly to simulate such scenarios. Fintech Companies mostly do that if the load is pretty less (say 100 users) and application they want to test is extremely critical and such applications cannot be tested using the standard api load tests as these are mostly legacy applications.

***I know, we can use JMeter to Mimic browser behaviour for load testing but is there anything different that real browser testing has to offer?***

Yes, real Browsers have JavaScript. Sometimes if implementation is poor on the front end (website), you cannot catch these issues using service level load tests. It makes sense to load test if you want to see how well the JS written by the developers or other logic is affecting page load times.

It is important to understand that performance testing is not limited to APIs alone but the entire user experience as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 types of test you need to consider:

1. **Backend** performance test: simulating X real users which are concurrently accessing the web application. The goal is to determine [relationship between increasing number of virtual users and response time/throughput](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/) (number of requests per second), identify [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html), first [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), etc.
2. **Frontend** performance test: protocol-based load testing tools don't actually render the page therefore even if response from the server came quickly it might be the case that due to a bug in client-side JavaScript rendering will take a lot of time therefore you might want to use real browser (1-2 instances) in order to collect [browser performance metrics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/performance)

Well-behaved performance test should check both scenarios, it's better to conduct main load using protocol-based tools and at the same time access the application with the real browser in order to perform client-side measurements.